# How is payroll tax calculated in Queensland?

Tags: australia, payroll-taxes

In [QLD Australia](https://qro.qld.gov.au/payroll-tax/calculate/rates-thresholds/) I can see the payroll tax rate is 4.75 or thereabouts.

I want to know how much my employer would pay on my behalf for payroll tax.

It doesn't need to be an exact value but more a generalized formula on how it is calculated.

I'm assuming it is calculated based on my income, lets say $100,000 and $10,000 super + benefits.

So is it $110,000 * .0475 = $5225 annually?

Comment: Payroll tax is not on your behalf. It's a tax on the employer, not on you. What's the reason you're asking? Is the employer asking you to reimburse them?

Comment: Im transitioning from employee to starting a business, so I want to know hoe to budget correctly when in comes to paying wages

Comment: You should probably work with an accountant.

Answer (score 2):

In Queensland, payroll tax is imposed by the [Payroll Tax Act 1971](https://www.legislation.qld.gov.au/view/html/inforce/current/act-1971-037). [Section 10](https://www.legislation.qld.gov.au/view/html/inforce/current/act-1971-037#sec.10) of the Act provides that the tax is 4.75% of the "taxable wages" paid by the employer, or 4.95% for employers with a payroll of over $6.5 million.

The [Dictionary](https://www.legislation.qld.gov.au/view/html/inforce/current/act-1971-037#sch) to the Act provides a detailed and complex definition for "wages," which is also [explained on the QRO website](https://qro.qld.gov.au/payroll-tax/liability/wages/). Relevantly to your question, the definition of "wages" includes  (c) remuneration for company directors, and (g) superannuation contributions.

[The QRO also explains](https://qro.qld.gov.au/payroll-tax/liability/wages/) that "if your annual Australian taxable wages are $1.3 million or less, you may not have to pay payroll tax." That is because [section 29](https://www.legislation.qld.gov.au/view/html/inforce/current/act-1971-037#sec.29) of the Act provides for a complicated "annual deduction" which offsets the tax for payrolls up to $1.3 million, and [reduces by $1 for every $7 of taxable wages over this amount](https://qro.qld.gov.au/payroll-tax/calculate/deductions/).

The deductions mean that payroll tax is gradually introduced and does not immediately apply to 4.75% of the entire payroll when the employer spends its first dollar over the $1.3 million threshold. However, it means that calculating the marginal tax for a single employee depends on the size of the employer, and other entities in the same corporate group, and their cashflow.

Broadly speaking, the tax can be estimated at 4.95% of base salary plus superannuation, if the employer's payroll is [more than $10.4 million](https://qro.qld.gov.au/payroll-tax/calculate/deductions/). If the payroll is less than $1.3 million, there is no payroll tax. Between these amounts, the tax steadily increases from 0% to 4.95%, in a complex way which depends on the employer's cashflow and can be determined with the [QRO calculators](https://qro.qld.gov.au/payroll-tax/calculate/calculators/).

Answer (score 0):

As set out in @sjy's excellent answer, payroll tax is levied at a particular rate on wage-like payments that exceed a threshold value.  If you're starting a small business with no employees or only a few employees, it's highly likely that you won't be liable for payroll tax.  But it would be worthwhile getting an accountant's advice on this and on a range of other financial issues that will face your new business.

Also note that each state and territory in Australia generally applies a similar approach to payroll tax but with different taxation rates and tax-free thresholds.

Another issue of concern for many businesses is that payroll tax is not payable simply on wages paid to employees.  There's sufficient scope in the payroll tax laws to allow each state's Revenue Office to interpret some payments to Independent Contractors as being "wage-like" and subject to payroll tax.  This is a huge concern to businesses such as medical practices where the individual doctors are usually running their own business and contracting with the landlord (the "medical centre") as an Independent Contractor.  Over the last couple of years, state Revenue Offices have begun levying payroll tax on Medical Centre operators in respect of payments to GPs who had been thought to be arms-length contractors, not employees.